# Why are my flags for comments being declined?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was under the impression a comment was temporary.  That said comments that do not add value to a question or answer that are of age, typically longer than 6 months old are to be flagged for removal.  I previously visited this discussion awhile ago and was encouraged to ask on meta.  Now, it would appear three flags I've made are denied:

1) [How to load Widget javascript + css files only if used?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30117/how-to-load-widget-javascript-css-files-only-if-used):

> great, Sorich's answer is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

2) [What's the difference between get_home_path() and ABSPATH?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188448/whats-the-difference-between-get-home-path-and-abspath):

> Good explanation! I was searching for this and you are straight to the
>   point.

3) [Hook into wp_head(); in a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167928/hook-into-wp-head-in-a-plugin):

> fantastic thanks shane

All Q&As are well over a year old so why are my flags declined as it would appear sometimes they're accepted under the same grounds that I've flagged them for but trying to do my part and help the site is becoming counterintuitive and I do not desire to be banned from flagging again.

Comment: I hope those commenters upvoted, why say +1 when you can literally +1 with a vote

Comment: I would hope so but sadly that is not always the case and they tend to need some encouraging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** - After talking it over with the other moderators it appears that I'm in the wrong here and the comments in the posts should have been removed. Comments should consist of:

- Question Clarification
- Additoinal Notes ( that may need to eventually be added to the post )

<s>Unfortunately, unlike post flags, comment flags don't appear to come with any sort of optional feedback.</s>

I don't consider the flagged comments to be "excessive noise" or "too chatty". It gives future readers more indication that the answer was helpful and it shows gratification to the answerer ( most the cases shown are from OP ). If there's many users expressing gratitude by commenting things like "Thanks" or "This worked" is usually when I've seen a thread become locked or protected to prevent this type of thing. If there's a long conversation then it would need to be moved to chat.

As it stands, a single comment from OP expressing gratitude isn't worth removing.

Comment: Trying to get me banned again I see, lol.  Its all good just trying to understand the logic.  Do you want me to re-flag them again?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ If you do I promise I won't dismiss them and actually remove them ( ya know, probably :D )

Comment: Re-flagged them for you and no worries, moderating is a learning process and takes time.

Answer (score 4):

While comments are [*not recommended*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to be used for compliments, please do consider if deleting *a four year old* thank you is productive use of your and moderator's time.

Did it *solve a problem*?

Comment: Well, I do not think it's counter productive when SE records how many comments moderators have removed.  I've always thought of it as site preventive maintenance if you will. . .